# How do I install Skype?

Tags: software-installation, skype

I want to install Skype, but I can't locate it in Software Center or by using Synaptic Package Manager. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 154):

### All Ubuntu releases as of July 2017

To install the Skype for Linux application (version 8+):

> 1. Download the [Deb package for Skype for Linux](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/) with your favourite web browser or HTTP client.
>
>    - For a terminal-based solution use:
>
>      ```
>      wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
>      ```
> 2. Install the Deb package with your favourite package manager, e. g. Software Center or GDebi.
>
>    - For a terminal-based solution or to debug the package installation use:
>
>      ```
>      sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
>      ```
> 3. You’re done! When you installed the package it automatically added a repository […] to keep your installation of Skype up to date via Ubuntu's package update process.

<sup>([source](/a/804498/175814))</sup>

The new Skype application works **only on 64-bit (amd64) installations of Ubuntu**.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installation via software center works!

Comment: @user2740: That's great! You should write an answer about it.

Answer (score 54):

Skype is now available in the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/skype) store.

[image]

### Skype snap package

Skype has been released as a snap package.

```
snap find skype
Name      Version      Developer  Notes    Summary
skype     8.14.0.10    skype      classic  One Skype for all your devices. New features. New look. All Skype.
```

To install Skype in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install skype --classic
```

The skype snap package will be updated automatically when updates are available.

Comment: and then? how to run skype after  installation?

Comment: Once Skype is installed the blue Skype icon will appear in the Dash like any other application's icon, and then click on the Skype icon to start Skype. If your OS doesn't have an application dashboard, then the Skype icon will appear in the applications menu with the rest of your installed applications.

Comment: i use this command snap run skype

Comment: Snap version of skype uses Firefox browser to open any link even if default browser was changed to something else.

Answer (score 14):

1. I went to the [Skype web site](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/).
2. Then I choose to "download Skype for Linux DEB".

   [image: Skype download page]
3. After the download I just double-click on the file or right-click and open with *Software Center* and click on *Install*.

   It will install the Deb package that you downloaded and after finishing you will find it by typing `Skype` in the search box. You can pin it's icon if you like.

   [image: install and run it]

Answer (score 6):

Installing packages manually is not recommended. But I have been installing Skype package manually for a quite some time through the Ubuntu Package manager without any problem. Just make sure you check any warning shown by during the installation.

Go to: http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/

Download the 64bit Ubuntu package. Once the download is finished, double click the package to start the installation through the Ubuntu Package manager. It will download any dependency and instal

Comment: Oh dear. This ubuntu ask makes me ask questions before having thought about the problem ;)
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Recently, [Skype](http://skype.com) has become very easy to get for Linux users. In fact, the package from the website works but the one in the repositories didn't for me (on Ubuntu 16.04). Just go to skype.com and [download](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/) the Debian **.deb file**, which you can open directly by double-clicking the downloaded file in the folder, and it will install through the software centre. As of now it's still in Beta version.

Answer (score 5):

### For the new (2017) client

Since 2017, Skype has stopped to support the old client and the new ones are not in Canonical’s partner repositories. In order to install the new client and have it automatically upgraded through `apt upgrade`, you can follow the recipe below, lifted from [websiteforstudents.com](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-upgrade-skype-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/) and tested on Ubuntu 17.10.

## 1. Remove the old Skype client

```bsh
# Either 
sudo apt remove skype
# or
sudo apt remove skypeforlinux
```

## 2. Ensure your prerequisites

```
sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
```

`apt-transport-https` allows you to `apt update` and `apt upgrade` from a .deb file on available on the web. `curl` will allow you to download Skype’s GPG key from the web.

## 3. Add skype.com’s deb to your apt source list

Firstly add Skype’s GPG key

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then create a file in apt source list containing package information, telling apt that it has to check skype.com for the repository.

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list`.
```

And update the repository

```
sudo apt update
```

## 4. Install Skype itself

```
sudo apt install skypeforlinux
```

`skypeforlinux` will be upgraded when needed, like the other Ubuntu softwares.

Comment: If you want to add an alternative way too, if you double click the `.deb` file which you can download on the skype site, all of the above mentioned gets installed and it even adds its own repository to the sources.

Answer (score 3):

Skype and some other popular applications can be currently (August 2017) installed with [Flatpack](http://flatpak.org/).

To use the latest version of Flatpack on Ubuntu, [it is recommended](http://flatpak.org/getting.html) to use a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

To install Skype with `flatpak` for all users, [execute](http://flatpak.org/apps.html#Skype):

```
flatpak install --from https://s3.amazonaws.com/alexlarsson/skype-repo/skype.flatpakref
```

After restarting the graphical shell or logging out and logging in, Skype should appear in application menus and in search results, and it then can be added to the *favourites*.  It can also be started from the command line with

```
flatpak run com.skype.Client
```

Answer (score 1):

First I was using snap to install skype, then apt-get install skypeforlinux, both installations when skype was running then, have shown irritating notification messages in the kind of "new update is available. Install latest version via your package manager, then restart skype". the apt update and upgrade did no help either.

So i removed it completely and installed skype via the browser: fetched the apt by browser and got it installed from  https://www.skype.com/de/get-skype/

the "new update is available..." notification have gone! Installed version is 8.56.0.103