# How do I install Skype in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find Skype in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-can-i-find-skype-in-the-software-center)

How can I install Skype on Oneiric?