# I installed sni-qt and there is no indicator for Skype. How do I fix this?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, indicator, skype

I upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10, installed sni-qt, and still have no Skype indicator. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to reinstall Skype.

The version of Skype that came with 11.04 will not work in 11.10 to besides, so you will need to remove it, and then install it again (from the software center). After this, Skype will work, and so will the indicator.

- [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)