# How to properly install Skype on 11.10 64bit

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

I wanted to install Skype on my fresh Ubuntu 11.10. I'm running on a 64 bit machine. When I go to the software center I only find skype:i386 but twice. When I try to install it, the software center tells me that in order to install skype the libary libc-bin has to be removed. I don't think this is what I want.

Is there any workaround to get Skype running on my machine?

Thanks in advance.