# What is the command line for skype installation?

Tags: installation, command-line, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

I am wondering what the command line is for the installation of skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb from the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx), Skype is part of the Canonical partner repository. To install Skype first you need to add the Canonical Partner Repository. You can do this by running the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then install Skype via the Software-Center or via the Terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

It is highly recommended to use the package provided in the Canonical partner repository, not the one distributed from the Skype website, as the Skype website currently points users to the wrong package for 64-bit systems of Ubuntu 11.10 and above.

---

Refer to [this community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype) for more details in case of any problems.

Comment: Hmmm, is that warning still current?

Answer (score 3):

Goto the directory in terminal where .deb file is saved.

run the following command:
`sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb`

Or type `sudo dpkg -i` and drag and drop `skype-ubuntu_2.2.0.35-1_i386.deb` file on the terminal and hit enter.

Note: This is not recommended to intall using `dpkg`. You should always install using from end of `dpkg` like `apt` to resolve dependency if any. However stand alone packages can be installed without any problem like skype.

More info: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html

Comment: If the packages has any dependences, it won't install properly. After `dpkg`, run `sudo apt-get install -f` to install the dependencies and fix the package.