# Skype not showing up in Software Center after installation

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

I installed Skype on 12.04 with the Software Center on my 64-bit machine after an upgrade from 11.10. I find Skype in the dash and Skype starts up ok. However if I look for it
in the Software Center it doesn't show up. On my other machine with a freshly installed 11.04 32-bit it does show up. In addition the Skype icon in the top Unity panel is missing on my 12.04 machine where as it is present on the 11.10 machine.

Any ideas?