# Can't install Skype through Software Center 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center, skype

New install of Ubuntu 12.04.1. Start Ubuntu Software Center. Edit menu > Software Sources > Other > tick the Canonical Partners sources. Click close.

Search for Skype. Skype app is not listed.

Following the [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype) I have reinstalled software center (surely there's a bug if the software center needs reinstalling after adding a source!), but still it does not show.

FYI: At a terminal `apt-cache search skype` lists skype and skype-bin.

I am comfortable at the command line, but people I am installing Ubuntu for are not. This is a real paper-cut - the first time I show them the software center, it doesn't work and I have to jump to command line.

So the question is: how to get it to show up in an easy-to-do user-friendly way?

PS. **Please do not mark this as a duplicate** of [how do I install skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype) unless that page is updated to actually answer this question (and presumably [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126016/cannot-locate-skype-in-software-center-12-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126449/skype-not-showing-up-in-software-center-after-installation)).

Comment: If it's not a dupe of the one that you link to, then isn't this a bug report to be filed against the Skype packages in the USC?

Comment: Please see the updated instructions in the Skype thread for installing in 12.04 and above.  Yes there is a problem with software center for some reason.  You can in install via command line, but software center is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 2):

Heres the better solution:

Download deb file [here](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/). Open terminal, cd to directory of downloaded skype and then run `sudo dpkg --install --force-all TheSkypeFileName.deb`. After installation, do not run skype, run this command instead `sudo apt-get install -f`, this will install all the dependencies. And your up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but **please see para 5 of the question**: I'm comfortable with getting skype installed, the point is that it's **supposed** to be easy (no terminal!). I think it's a bug in software center, and as this is the official channel for asking about these things, I'm asking it here.

Comment: Did `sudo apt-get update` return no errors?

Comment: Correct: no errors.

Comment: Now try again restarting software center and look if skype is listed.

Comment: yep, done that. even reinstalled it. still not listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't see it if you have the Partner repository enabled, but the community help page at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype says the skype website points to the wrong package for 64-bit 11.10 and above, which is why you're seeing 386 libraries. If you look at some of the third-party instructions out there, you'll see instructions for 64-bit Precise/Quantal that point to Lucid 32-bit packages.

Comment: Thank you. But again, I want to be able to install through the software centre. It's not much of an Ubuntu "partner" if this that is supposed to work...doesn't. Think I'll try a bug report

Comment: Also, that community wiki just tells me to do the thing that is not working " It is highly recommended to use the package provided in the Canonical partner repository, not the one distributed from the skype website"

Answer (score -1):

Use these:

1. `sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype`

first command will add the reepository for skype .
then just update and install skype.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This answer would benefit substantially, if you were to edit it to add some explanation (or at least to tell the user exactly *what to do* with these lines).