# Why are some programs in the Ubuntu Software Center not open source?

Tags: software-center, license

I'm concerned about the amount of proprietary software that seems to be part of Ubuntu now. I've noticed quite a few apps that in the software center are listed as "Licence: proprietary".

Obviously there's the partner stuff, like Skype (although that's not good example as it [doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231004/cant-install-skype-through-software-center-12-04#comment295543_231004) in the Software Center) but there seems to be a fair load of other stuff creeping in, too.

Is there something I've not understood here? Is it all in partner or is some proprietary stuff in the main Ubuntu repos?

Is there a way to filter for FOSS?

The open source bit is important to me - I don't just want a free-beer OS as I think open source software model is better. Debian is strictly FOSS (AFAIK), for example.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Several repositories

Ubuntu features various repositories with its own policies on the software being included there.

Summarized from [Community Wiki - Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Components):

- **main** contains applications that are free software, can be freely redistributed and are fully supported by the Ubuntu team.

  *This is the fully-FOSS section.*
- **restricted** Our commitment is to only promote free software – or software available under a free licence. However, we make exceptions for a small set of tools and drivers that make it possible to install Ubuntu and its free applications on everyday hardware.
- **universe** is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world. It houses almost every piece of open-source software, all built from a range of public sources. Canonical does not provide a guarantee of regular security updates for software in the universe component

  [*Open source, maybe FOSS*](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html)
- **multiverse** component contains software that is not free, which means the licensing requirements of this software do not meet the Ubuntu main component licence policy. [...] not supported and usually cannot be fixed or updated. Use it at your own risk.

These are the "regular" repositories which the Software Center uses to list the applications available.

#### Additional software (partners)

Additional to the above, there's the Extras and the Partner repositories. You'll have to enable those by yourself as an opt-in. The partner repository is more or less privately held by Canonical. It includes proprietary software in it, without source code available usually, just for reasons of being partners with Canonical or other commercial reasons.

Some costless "apps" in the Software Centre are provided via the Extras repository, and have to adhere to the [Extension Repository Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ExtensionRepositoryPolicy). These list just a few (see below).

The apps submitted via the [MyApps programme](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/) are another story and very much Ubuntu specific. Source code is not always available and you can find some relevant information on the [MyApps commercial software FAQ](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/). Some are commercial and closed-source only, provided via a Private PPA with APT-HTTPS authentication. The ones distributed in this way don't have to adhere to any policies apart from the Launchpad PPA policies and [some technical requirements](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/) - they're fairly private to the developers.

#### What about package x, y and z?

To see in which component a certain application is included, I suggest to go to [`packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), find the package, and in the page title you'll notice the section in brackets, e.g. `Package: kcalc (4:4.9.2-0ubuntu1) [universe]`.

#### Can I run my system with only FOSS software?

To filter for FOSS-only, just *only* enable `main` (and optionally `universe`) - just to make sure you don't let in close-source software. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to exclude these if you like. You may run into issues running your hardware correctly as indicated by the description of the **restricted** component above.

Whether it will be very functional depends on your hardware and requirements you hold to the software you'd like to use. Some mainstream hardware doesn't require any proprietary firmware/binaries and can run perfectly fine without any closed source piece of data. The *restricted* and *multiverse* components provide a generally acceptable balance in this for most people, but you need turn them off in case you want to completely FOSS.

The set of applications you can pick will considerably scale down if you decide to disable the *universe* component. The [list of all packages in Quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/allpackages?format=txt.gz) has these numbers to give you some idea:

- main (+ security): 14250
- universe: 32595
- multiverse: 746
- restricted: 14

I was unable to find a credible source for the additional repositories, so by just using the regular Packages.gz files (assuming Quantal amd64):

- [extras](http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz): 9
- [partner](http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/partner/binary-amd64/Packages.gz): 9

#### See also

- [Ubuntu Free software philosophy](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy)
- [Extension Repository Policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ExtensionRepositoryPolicy)
- [How to remove the “For Purchase” section from the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47997/88802)

Comment: +1. I would personally mention that there's difference between 'free software' and 'open source software' (which is explained in the Philosophy page you linked). I would also state that commercial != proprietary and free as in free beer != free as in freedom. (Without going into boring details, of course.)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Yeah... I know. I could go into all the details here, but 1) I'm not good at these details and 2) I personally don't care *that* much about these details. Give me some time to include at least some important details. :)

Comment: Does removing main/universe stop the software center from displaying non-OSS apps?

Comment: @JorgeCastro I guess a lot of dependencies won't be able to be met anymore then... :) `main` is really needed for most applications - e.g. the kernel for example. Or do you mean removing restricted/multiverse/extras/partner?

Comment: Well, I was thinking more about the banners and whatnot, like this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/47997/how-to-remove-the-for-purchase-section-from-the-software-center

Comment: @gertvdijk thank you for such a clear answer. I feel more confident in understanding Ubuntu's role in building the open source community now, thanks.

Comment: **Basically, it's multiverse**. Get rid of that after installing the good FOSS stuff therein or be forever hounded by proprietary stuff.

Comment: From my experience you can't. I've been trying to remove the non-foss software but no luck. Repositories do not affect snaps for example. I tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 by disabling and enabling repositories and no luck at all. Proprietary software is still in the Ubuntu Software Center. Therefore my answer is that this is either a bug, or something Canonical is doing on purpose.

I could not get an answer to this either after posting on AskUbuntu "Why is there proprietary software in Ubuntu Software Center?"

Answer (score 2):

If you disable snaps using `sudo apt purge gnome-software-plugin-snap` as shown [in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre), and then in Ubuntu Software Center, go to Software & Updates > Ubuntu and uncheck the option that says "Software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)" I think that will remove all the non-FOSS results.  At least, no proprietary results have shown up in my searches so far after doing so.

...except for drivers - uncheck the "restricted" option to get rid of those as well