# Ubuntu License for companies

Tags: license

I'm really concerned because a need to know if Ubuntu is totally free for a company. I mean, if I use a private software, I have to pay that license package, but Have I to pay for use Ubuntu? Have I to get a license?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Simply put Ubuntu is open source and free for anyone to use, including commercial use. Nice, huh!?

However looking at it more closely, you see that Ubuntu consists of a lot of individual packages and each can have its own license. That's important to keep in mind about *redistributing* software as not all software in all repositories is fully [FOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software). See also my answer to [Why are some programs in the Ubuntu Software Center not open source?](https://askubuntu.com/q/251601/88802).

I suggest you to read up on [Ubuntu Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is typically free to use.  Canonical (the backers of Ubuntu) provide enterprise support for the Desktop, Cloud, and Server OS which costs money.  However, that's just part of an enterprise maintenance agreement.