# How can I disable snaps in gnome-software centre?

Tags: software-installation, snap

Software center does not differentiate between snap and normal applications.

Is there anyway to change this behavior or disable the snaps in the software center altogether as I have not need for them ?

The main issue is they don't work with your theme and look horrible.

Comment: Have you ever checked this forum post?
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152
I hope removing snapd would help.

Comment: I had not seen that, although i don't have an issue with snapd running as i can download and install snaps when i want them. it would be nicer to be able to remove just from software centre so I get debs over snaps.

Comment: Try removing this package & see if that helps.. `gnome-software-plugin-snap`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pretty simple, just remove this package, stop & restart gnome-software. (easiest thing to do is just reboot..

```
sudo apt purge gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Then reboot & you'll not see snaps in gnome or ubuntu software app

Comment: then reboot ???!, This is not windows

Comment: I assume he meant restart the program, not the OS. Hey, this command doesn't work in Focal Fossa, any ideas?

Comment: Well by default 20.04 uses snap-store so no plugin needed. You could remove snap-store, i.e sudo snap remove snap-store then install gnome-software package..

Comment: What this command is exactly doing?

Answer (score 11):

I also dislike snaps.  I don't use them, and it's annoying how it's always phoning home for updates.  Unfortunately in Lubuntu 16.04, `lubuntu-desktop` has a dependency on `snapd`, so it's awkward to just remove it.

You can at least permanently kill it by doing

```
sudo systemctl stop snapd
sudo systemctl disable snapd
```

Comment: Do it with a single command: `systemctl disable snapd --now`

Comment: @TheGripmaster thanks! BTW, this post is old, IIRC 18.04 Lubuntu doesn't have the dependency so I could just remove the whole mess.

Comment: I am wondering if you found a way to get rid of this snap annoyance in Ubuntu 20.04? I posted a question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585357/avoiding-snap-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: @TheGripmaster check this out: https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to disable - described above - here is a very good article with instruction for cleaning up your system more elaboretly:
https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/
**note** The link seems to be broken at the moment - but the below instructions should do the work anyway.

It basically says:

1. do `snap list`
2. `snap remove` all items (by dependency order)
3. `apt purge snapd`
4. clear various files at `/home/*/snap`, `/usr/lib/snap` and alike

In case of the server the only snap was lxd - something Canonical is pushing as an alternative to docker.

IMHO this a bit of a conflict of interests between Canonical and the users. Users should be able to opt-in whatever they need and not be forced to uninstall stuff the hard way..

Comment: You forgot to add a entry blacklist to apt preferences.d `uck-snapd.pref 
Package: snapd
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -9000` Otherwise it will keep resurrecting like a zombie

Comment: URL no longer working

Answer (score 1):

Try in the command line:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

use Synaptic package manager to delete Snapd. You can remove Snapd, the snapd login service, and libsnapd-glib1. As I recall do NOT enter it in the system log, but it probably is in the Synaptic log.....) it was a clean remove and freed up some disk space, got rid of the loops on the HD. If you have Synaptic, remove everything snapd. If you do not have synaptic then sudo apt-get update and sudo apt install Synaptic should get you the package manager. I use either Aptitude, apt or Synaptic on my system to make sure dependencies are handled. Aptitude is the most through but can cause problems because it is aggressive, apt is better from the terminal and Synaptic works well since it has a nice GUI front end. Hope all of this helps.
                                                              or
Removed the following packages:
snap-confine
snapd
ubuntu-core-launcher
Upgraded the following packages:
snap-confine (2.22.2) to 2.22.3
snapd (2.22.2) to 2.22.3
ubuntu-core-launcher (2.22.2) to 2.22.3
Removed the following packages:
libsnapd-glib1
snapd
snapd-login-service

Upgraded the following packages:
tcpdump (4.7.4-1ubuntu1) to 4.9.0-1ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1

why did snapd reinstall an updated package if I ripped snapd out by the roots, yes?
open a terminal and run sudo Nautilus and when the file manager opens, I searc for snapd. Find several folders and a bunch of files, highlighted them all and deleted then .However after removing all of this gradu,  reboot the machine......  shut down and boot in verbose mode to try to read the rapid text that flashes by and spot problems. Clean reboot. So far operating normally

Answer (score 0):

The issue with just uninstalling `snap`/`snapd` is that Ubuntu is (extremely annoyingly) migrating a bunch of their packages into snaps, which will then reinstall `snapd`.

To block any packages that depend on snaps from being *installed* permanently:

```
echo "Package: snapd" | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/block-snapd
echo "Pin: release *" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/block-snapd
echo "Pin-Priority: -1" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/preferences.d/block-snapd
```

This effectively prevents `snapd`, and any packages that depend on `snapd` from getting installed:

```
durr@atombox:/etc/apt/preferences.d$ sudo apt install chromium-browser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chromium-browser : PreDepends: snapd but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The error about broken packages is ironic, since it's true (as `snapd` and all packages that use it are garbage), but not the way apt implies it.