# How can I disable access to the Snap Store?

Tags: snap

I want to build and install snaps locally, not from the Snap Store. For example, `snap install foo` should fail and Snap Store apps should not appear in GNOME Software.

How can I keep Snap, but disable/remove the Snap Store?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/984250/15811 (?)

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm aware of that part of the solution, but it doesn't solve snap install foo, or the general premise of unplugging from the snap store, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You could firewall off the store by setting all the host names the store uses to `127.0.0.1` in your `/etc/hosts` file. That way you get to keep the ability to build and install snaps locally, but `snapd` will never reach the store.

Adding `127.0.0.1     api.snapcraft.io` to `/etc/hosts` will likely be sufficient.