# Disabling Snaps in Gnome or Ubuntu Software in 20.04

Tags: software-center, snap, 20.04

This same question was discussed for older versions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982112/how-can-i-disable-snaps-in-gnome-software-centre) . But the solution provided `sudo apt purge gnome-software-plugin-snap`
 doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04. In 20.04, it shows

```
Package 'gnome-software-plugin-snap' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

If I am searching in Ubuntu Software for VLC media player, Ubuntu suggests snap package even when VLC is available without snap. I always prefer non-snap software when it is available. How can I disable snap softwares from Ubuntu Software. I don't want to uninstall snap completely since I may need to use it to certain specific applications.

Comment: So why not use the terminal to install synaptic package manager and then use that?

Comment: Use synaptic package manager, it only shows   .deb's. If you have a proper working ubuntu software in 20.04 then the deb vlc would be at bottom of results with generic icon. If you upgraded to 20.04 from prior release then you won't have a proper working Ubuntu-software which is actually a snap, I.e snap-store

Comment: Almost all apps are also available as DEB as it always was. They kind of force us to start using snaps. The only solution I had was to install all the app via the terminal. But Kevin Custer has a way of extracting all snaps and preventing you from installing snaps. He made it for 20.04 and 20.10 but it also works for 21.04. https://www.kevin-custer.com/blog/disabling-snaps-in-ubuntu-20-04/