# Skype on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

I've lost my Skype application after upgrading to 12.04 LTS. I wanted to download it from Skype.com to reinstall, but they don't have a version for 12.04. What should I do?