# ia32-lib package damaged!

Tags: 64-bit, skype

Let me start by saying I have no idea what ia32-lib is but I hate it because it's apparently not working for me i know because I've been trying to install Skype for a month now and i have asked on almost every forum on the Internet. So without further ado this is what happens when i attempt to install Skype (I am 64x Bit)

Link to error: http://pastebin.com/n43FSXMh
In short i get "Package operation failed".

If you can fix this you are a magician.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 1):

Since I am guessing you're using `dpkg`, you need to install all dependencies with `apt` before the final `dkpg` step, so run:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

first.

Then, try `sudo dpkg -i file.deb` where file.deb is the Skype package you downloaded.

Comment: Nope, I have got the application now with it's icon but when I click it, It does not open nothing happens

Comment: What happens when you run it in the terminal via `skype`? Try rebooting as it may help.

Comment: how do I run it in terminaal?

Comment: Just run `skype`.