# How can I install Skype?

Tags: 12.10, skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Respected sir, would you please help me to install Skype.

Comment: Ok I am sorry and thank you for the valuable information dear.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:
1.Ubuntu Software Center, search for Skype
2.Skype website and click the download link
3.sudo apt-get install skype

64-bit may having some installation problem

Comment: Thank you, Huei! The command line was the right solution in my case...