# Why does my Ubuntu 12.10 not look like examples in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: unity

What front-end/theme/etc. is shown on
[How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

I am a rank novice and installed Ubuntu from the web (forgot the site).
It runs fine, but examples I find in various support forums don't look like my screens.

Comment: Could be, you've got something other then Ubuntu from that site you forgot of.

Comment: obtain an iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/ and install. This will look exactly the way you want.

Comment: What does your screenshot look like? Include a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install different desktop envoirements. Therefore, you can 100% modify your desktop.

If you are novice, you ought to know that.

In the given thread they probably use gnome or Unity. But those screens only show the content of a given window, so it's hard to tell.