# I have problems to install Skype after a distro upgrade

Tags: installation, skype, libraries

1. I have numerous time updated the software center.
2. Upgraded the system using `sudo apt-get upgrade` and also `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Went through a lot of tutorials.
4. Downloaded skype from there site.
5. Tried to install through terminal.
6. Review [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype).

Below are the details of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.1)]/ quantal main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted         universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ hardy main
deb-src http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ hardy main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

But still unable to install Skype. It gives me the old fashioned several lib     dependency errors. Also when I try to install the `.deb` package downloaded from their site, it gives `skype-bin error`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install skype` should just work, perhaps giving slightly out of date version at worst. Could you add the output to the command to your question? And also `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Please add it to the question by editing it. It is hard to read in comments

Comment: I have edited the question and added the detail.

Comment: Could you please also add the output to the `sudo apt-get install skype` command? Do you remember why those lines containing `hardy` are still there? Has this machine been updated since 8.04?

Comment: I installed 12.10 version. I have also gave the answer in this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/250145/how-to-install-skype-in-linux/250303#250303) that how I successfully installed skype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to select all the options in

#### Muon software center>settings>configure software sources>software sources>other Software

and then update, upgrade the sources, also try to select the best server in the settings. It will update all the sources. That's it. It will add the skype sources and will update the dependencies and then you can install directly from the software center.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd path/to/skype/deb/downloaded/from/skype.com
sudo dpkg -i skype*
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: its giving me "Errors were encountered while processing:
 flareget
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb
```

And you are done.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing Skype from the official Skype website gave errors, but installing from the standard repositories worked perfectly.

So my suggestion is to uninstall Skype:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'skype*'
```

And then install directly from the standard repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```