# Skype not working after upgrading to 13.04 from 12.10

Tags: upgrade

I upgraded to 13.04 from 12.10. now Skype wont launch. i have reinstalled it but still will not work.i have tried ideas in this post, but still not working. [I have problems to install Skype after a distro upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250145/i-have-problems-to-install-skype-after-a-distro-upgrade) any ideas would be a help thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This should work: [source: LinuxG.net](http://linuxg.net/yet-another-way-to-make-skype-run-under-ubuntu-13-04/)

Open the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf file, in your favourite text editor, as root:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/skype.conf
```

Paste the following line:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/
```

Run ldconfig:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -v
```

This is it. Enjoy.

Comment: thank you .it worked. i don’t know what it did but im glad it works.Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome & Skype  has a bug and can't be installed on fresh Ubuntu 13.04 installations. The bug currently affects Google Chrome Stable and Beta and skype (has already been fixed in Google Chrome Dev) and until Google fixes it (it's not an Ubuntu bug), you can easily get Google Chrome and skype to install by downloading and installing the deb below:

- [libudev0 for 32bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/175-0ubuntu19/+build/4325790/+files/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_i386.deb)
- [libudev0 for 64bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/175-0ubuntu19/+build/4325788/+files/libudev0_175-0ubuntu19_amd64.deb)

After install that package you will be able to install skype in Ubuntu 13.04

See this 'www.webupd8.org/2013/04/7-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html' it contain 7 things to do after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the config files

```
rm -fr ~/.Skype
```

If that doesn't work, you may want to purge

```
sudo apt-get purge skype*
```

and then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

MY skype would not start after an update from 12.10 to 13.04. the following helped me start it again. (Acer Aspire One 725 C60 netbook w/ ubuntu & 8gb RAM)

> in a terminal window do:
>
> `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 skype`
>
> You may also want to try this variant:
>
> `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/FGL.renamed.libGL.so.1.2.0 skype`

Source of commands above. thanks to gunnarHj for the solution.
http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/ubuntu-13-04/td-p/1455552/page/4

The above solution makes a reference to (you may want to read this for a more permanent solution):
[Skype Crashes with a Segmentation fault](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285642/skype-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault)