# How to install skype Ubuntu 12.04 and later

Tags: software-installation

Many people are having troubles during Skype installation, because dpkg commands change in later Ubuntu releases. Method I am using is mentioned [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/316134/236618).

Answer (score -2):

Edited to be in the Q/A format. Upvote CombatBadger, not me.

In this case command 'dpkg --add-architecture i386' is DEPRECATED and you should use 
'dpkg --assert-multi-arch' to get Skype working.

### Method to install Skype on Ubuntu 12.04 and later

Terminal input:

```
sudo dpkg --assert-multi-arch
sudo apt-get install ia32-libst
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Skype for Linux (MultiArch) from [Skype.com](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading/?type=ubuntu64)

Have a good time!

Comment: You should make this answer [Community Wiki](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) since you didn't actually write it.

Comment: @Seth is up to the OP if he want's to be CW'fied. I really don't see any worth in keeping a duplicated of the same question around.

Comment: @Braiam It it's a duplicate question we should close it..

Comment: @Seth no votes...

Comment: BTW, the `ia32-libst` package is not available in 13.04 onwards. You should test the answer before giving them.

Comment: @Braiam Check the question's revision history. He's trying to keep the site clean and working, it's not *his* answer. Hence the CW proposal.

Comment: Can't figure out how to CW it...I'm fine with it; does anybody mind telling me how?