# dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture.

Tags: software-installation

When I try to do

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
[sudo] password for shailendra: 
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture.
```

this happens while installing skype.

Comment: Read through [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype/).

Comment: There is no `-add-architecture` option in dpkg running on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/423122/72576).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to install Skype this way?

1. Add repository via terminal

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list'
   ```
2. Tell your system to pull down the latest list of software from each archive it knows about via the terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install Skype via terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype
   ```

Maybe this way of installation will help you.

Comment: problem with adding i386 architecture only.