# Cannot install Skype - broken packages

Tags: package-management, skype

STORY: skype wasn't working properly, so i removed it to install it again.

```
 sudo apt-get remove skype
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

PROBLEM: when i

```
 sudo apt-get install skype
```

it gives an broken packages error. I want to fix it with synaptics package manager but when i click: fix broken packages, it returns an error.

QUESTION: what do I do now? I desperately need skype.

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:

```
 sudo apt-get purge skype
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo apt-get clean
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I have also tried downloading from the website, it gives an error while installing: cannot install libqt4-dbus:i386

When I try to install it from the commandline, it says: missing dependencies: skype-bin

when I try

```
sudo apt-get install skype-bin
```

it says missing dependencies: libqt4-dbus:i386 and a whole lot of other packages. When I try to install one of those packages it misses some other packages. What do i have to do?
Thanks in advance,

---

Sorry, I cannot paste output in here. I needed Skype for my work and it was not working for a couple of days so I was forced to completely remove Ubuntu. I only run windows at the moment but will install Kubuntu very soon. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `dpkg -l | grep skype`

Comment: rc  skype-bin                                   4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1               i386         client for Skype VOIP and instant messaging service - binary files

Comment: I'm missing Skype-bin

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge skype-bin`

Comment: done, still not installing!

Comment: When I try to

     sudo apt-get install skype-bin

it says i miss a lot of packages

Comment: Hmm.. Could it possibly be a problem with the repository mirror you are using? You may want to try "Main server" in Software & Updates.

Comment: I already have that selected

Comment: Ok, I'm out of ideas. Think it would be a good idea if you edited the question, as someone suggested, so it includes the current status and everything you've tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)