# What is SkypeWebPlugin.pkg and why is it required?

Tags: skype

I just started with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed Skype, it seems to work, but without sound or video(internet radio, Youtube = OK).

This "SkypeWebPlugin.pkg" is required. The file type is unknown, an application could not be found.

I tried to reinstall Skype, the reply in the terminal window "0 pakketten opgewaardeerd, 0 pakketten nieuw geïnstalleerd, 0 te verwijderen en 8 niet opgewaardeerd", "8 not upgraded".
Thanks for your help.

Comment: .pkg files are used on OSX, typically. How did you install skype?

Comment: Did you attempt to install Skype from the Skype website using a Mac pkg? That's not the way to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: I would advise you to find a different program, as the Skype version for Ubuntu is outdated, buggy, and won't be supported in 2017 (when 12.04 goes EOL).

Comment: Sorry, @SuperSluether, but you are wrong. Admittedly it's outdated compared to the Windows version and buggy, but the fact that 12.04 goes EOL has nothing to do with it (despite of the confusing name of the package file). Besides. "find a different program" is easy to say, but a rather useless advice if those who you want to communicate with use Skype.

Comment: @ RolndiXor : I downloaded it from Skype.com, Skype for Linux.  Please tell me: wich distribution do I use for my 14.04 LTS? What is the command to install it? Thank you so much

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson When 12.04 goes EOL, so do it's repositories. If Skype depends on any software or libraries from that version, bye-bye Skype.

Comment: @SuperSluether: Skype is available in the [repositories of all supported Ubuntu versions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype). Later Ubuntu versions do of course not depend on libraries in the 12.04 repository.

Comment: @JM.Beckers: As regards general info about installing Skype, please see e.g. [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype) or [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-chat-skype.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A package file is for OS X. At this time, the skype web version does not have a plugin for Linux based systems.

You can use the official skype app though.

Comment: OK, thank you.  I had no choice, the Ubuntu version was automaticly installed. How do I switch to the Skype app?

Comment: My bad, I meant the skype desktop application. To install that, download the DEB of skype.com and navigate to where you downloaded it. (cd Downloads) now run, dpkg -i skype-xxxxx (the xxxxx is the full file name.) If you get dependencies errors, just run sudo apt-get install -f