# I can't install Skype on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, skype

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 now and I'm having problem with installing skype, when I tried to install skype, it turned out like this:

```
sudo apt-get install Skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Skypes guy
```

Can you guys help me please?

Comment: The package name is `skype` (not `Skype`). Btw, have you [enabled Canonical Partner](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Answer (score 5):

all the previous version of skype has been outdated on July,1st 2017. So in order to install skype for linux download .deb file from link https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ and after download

1. Go to the download directory and open terminal
2. Type command `sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb`

All done !!

Comment: https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb Use this link to download and then the command in the directory you have this file use that command

Answer (score 1):

Command line way:

Open Terminal & copy paste the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/   $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Not working. Still it is not showing. Instead it is showing "skypeforlinux" and for "skype" it is giving same error

Comment: @SeeTheC are you sure you typed all the commands correctly?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem... after enabling Canonical Partners in Software & Updates, updating, and rebooting, I still get "E: Unable to locate package skype"

Comment: @DaniCee that's not what I did. You need to (in your terminal) copy and paste the above commands. Enabling Canonical Partners in Software & Updates does not (to my knowledge) add the required repository for "skype." If you are having trouble with this, I believe there is a .deb package in Synaptic Package manager that will install Skype for you. Please ensure you have copied and pasted the above commands *EXACTLY* or else it won't work. Also, this answer is a year old, so the information may be outdated, but I have not checked.

Comment: I also tried the commands and Skype couldn't still be located... I have opened this new discussion, if you can have a look (https://askubuntu.com/questions/932116/ubuntu-16-04-cannot-locate-skype-after-enabling-canonical-partners-in-software/932118?noredirect=1#comment1476194_932118)

Comment: As of July 15, 2017, the result of this command sequence is "E: Unable to locate package skype".

Comment: @Tony go to https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ and download the .deb package. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the website and download the deb file and then sudo dpkg -i install it
https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to install skype will be **snap**. I was troubled with this installation for long. On trying the installation using the Software Updater of Ubuntu, I was getting span error. Then I went through this step, and found this simplest method of snap.

**snap** is providing the installation of skype. Use these steps in command line.

> ***Step 1***: snap find "skype"
>
> ***Step 2***: sudo snap install skype --classic

After the execution, skype window opens and then you can continue.

For more details of snap, and its errors, use the link https://itsfoss.com/snapd-error-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

What I did was typed the following commands in terminal,

```
sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin:i386 skype:i386
sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386
rm -rf ~/.Skype
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I used this link: [Click here for download](http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb), it automatically downloaded the file for me.Clicking on that file led to the Ubuntu Software center from where I installed.And it works now.

Comment: Giving error after executing "sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb". Error "Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386"

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the above worked. Bit of a workaround but Franz gives you full function Skype client, WhatsApp client and more on Linux. 
Works like a charm for me >> https://github.com/meetfranz/franz-app/releases/download/4.0.4/Franz-linux-x64-4.0.4.tgz