# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot locate Skype after enabling Canonical Partners in Software & Update

Tags: apt, skype, canonical

I am experiencing this problem for the first time with Ubuntu 16.04, after a fresh installation.

Skype cannot be located after enabling Canonical Partners both in Software & Update, or by command line with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/   $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then running the following:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```

However, I still get:

> E: Unable to locate package skype

Any clue?

**UPDATE**

I run "sudo apt-get update --fix-missing" before trying to install skype, and this is the output I get:

```
Hit:1 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:5 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:6 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 306 kB in 3s (79.5 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
```

I try "sudo apt-get install skype" again, and I obtain:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

Comment: I tried that, both Qasim's answer, and the accepted answer enabling Canonical Partners in Sotware & Updates... still Skype cannot be located

Comment: All Skype for Linux clients version 4.3 and older retired on July 1, 2017.

Comment: This is the correct answer https://askubuntu.com/a/932182/167850

Answer (score 5):

The legacy Skype for Linux application was discontinued and removed from Canonical's partner repositories. You can [install the new Skype for Linux application](/a/932189/175814) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed recently this way:

Add Skype repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Add i386 architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

Update and install

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Answer (score -1):

DaniCee!

I think I have a solution for your problem. Of course, there's the terminal way which hasn't worked for you, but I'll put here for redundancy's sake.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/    $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Now that we've covered option 1, your second option is to simply search in  Synaptic. Make sure it's "skype" with a lowercase s, and not "Skype" with an uppercase S. I was able to find it in Synaptic, but that may be because I have Skype installed already.

Finally, you can simply to this website https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/ and click the download .deb option and voila! skype.deb is now available to download manually (is that considered manual?). Hope this helps out!

Comment: The first path won’t work any more. -1 (see my answer for an explanation)