# Multiple problems revolving around ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, skype

I just freshly installed the latest Ubuntu and I have a few problems:

Packages such as Skype won't show after selecting Canonical packages

Software & Updates menu:

[image]

Once I select them and close, it complains they are out of date and it needs to be updated. I authorise and let it do it's thing but it brings me to this:

[image]

I'm loving Ubuntu so far and I'm considering overwriting Windows 10 with it, if I can get these bugs squashed.

Comment: Please check your internet connection and be sure its working, then use this [example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype) to install skype.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Skype?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)

Comment: I'd recommend keeping Windows 10 in a dual-boot configuration. You may need it to do BIOS updates, get support from the manufacturer, or run Windows apps for which there is no Ubuntu counterpart.

Answer (score 0):

Skype not being shown in Ubuntu Software is a [known issue](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1567630). You can install it from terminal instead:

```
sudo apt install skype
```

As regards the other message, it's probably what it says. You may want to open *Software & Updates* and try another download server.