# Skype in Linux: No device found for Audio, microphone, Camera

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, skype

I followed [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype/932189#932189) to install Skype into my Linux. Chat is working fine but **Audio**, **microphone**, **Camera** is not working. When I checked in Skype under **Tools > Audio Video Settings** then I found that it's showing `No device found`.

Comment: Skype needs pulseaudio, and older versions of Lubuntu don't have it. `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`.

Comment: I have this problem -- almost: my camera is working, but not the audio. I get the system pings, but no sound at all via "Echo service", nor in the audio settings test. When I check the audio in `Settings > Sound > Applications`, "Skype" is showing with a Chromium icon. So I tried Jason David Hartzell's suggestion ... it the Chromium "Skype" extension (from www.skype.com) works perfectly. I'm running 18.04 pre-release, and Pulseaudio 11.1 is installed. Odd. It would still be good to have the "proper" client working properly, but at least I can use Skype on this machine now.

Comment: I tried deb, snap and chromium plugin on Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS but nothing worked. I have Pulseaudio 11.1 installed. Goodbye Skype!

Comment: If KDE is used then you need to remove `~/.config/kmixrc` file and restart Skype.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the editor Atom.

I found out that whenever I open Atom, Skype will not find any devices (no sound, no microphon, no camera).

However if I close Atom, and then start Skype, everything is shown. If I start Atom after Skype, everything will still work.

Very strange, but maybe it helps if you just close everything before starting Skype in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: I don't have Atom, but I do have Visual Studio Code and both use the same Electron base, so after following your steps Skype worked again!

Comment: Same here, on Fedora 38 with VS Code running, Skype's audio settings only show a microphone "default device" and test call does not hear me.  If I quit Skype and VS Code, then run Skype again, the Microphone list includes my "HD Webcam C525 Pro" and audio works.  Running VS Code again does not break it, it still works.  And weirdly, quitting Skype at that point and running it again, it still works.

Answer (score 4):

After a long investigation, I finally found the solution. Just remove the contents of the `$HOME/.config/pulse/` (or rename the `pulse` to `pulse.BAK` to be safer).

I had old files created by the previous Linux installation. After removing those files Skype runs perfectly on every start.

Comment: This worked for my flatpak installation of Skype after closing most running applications.

Comment: This worked for me too. Flatpak install on Pop OS. I renamed the directory and restarted.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried many of the 'old' solutions in the blog posts. There is a very simple solution. Download Google Chrome internet browser, go to 'extensions' type SKYPE, and download the first SKYPE extension. An icon will appear on the Chrome toolbar for skype - click it! sign in... And... you're done ;-)

Comment: Works for me - thanks! See further detail in [my comment to OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986810/skype-in-linux-no-device-found-for-audio-microphone-camera#comment1606447_986810).

Comment: This is not a solution. The problem is with the native linux client and/or some interaction with audio/video in recent linux distribs. This solution suggests using something other than the native linux client.