# How do I upgrade Skype using terminal on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, skype

I need to upgrade my `skype version` using terminal. Right now I have the Skype version `8.11.0.4` and the notification icon I am getting the text, i.e.

```
A new update is available. Install latest version via your package manager, then restart skype.
```

So I need to upgrade the latest version using terminal. I need the steps to upgrade this.

Comment: if youhave the repo installed, then `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: @ravery : I have already one version `8.11.0.4` and i Need to update it.

Comment: it will update it

Comment: @ravery : I did as per you but it gave me this `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype
` message.

Comment: see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/932189/694267

Answer (score 36):

If you have the  Skype repo added to your system (If you installed it from the `.deb` package provided in the official Skype website, the repo is added automatically.), you may run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
```

or simply run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to install all* available updates.

Answer (score 5):

Download new version of skype for linux from(https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/)

- Open the deb file with **Ubuntu Software center**
- You will find **upgrade** option for skype, Just go for it.