# Skype signing issue in Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, skype

I've just installed skype on my ubuntu machine.
But when I starts login, it gets disappeared without any error.

I've tried most of options available online, but still same issue persists.

Anyone can help what can be done to fix this issue..?

Comment: How did you install Skype? Did you download Skype from the internet or did you install the native [Skype snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype/1002299#1002299) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

May I know which version skype you are using.

And let me tell you one thing from past few months, Skype keeps upgrading its version (almost every week) it releases a new version. I would suggest you to upgrade the Linux Skype version.

TRY THE BELOW COMMAND.

**sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux** .

Hope this will fix your issue.