# Lubuntu Skype don't Open

Tags: lubuntu, skype

I installed Skype on Lubuntu from "Gnome software". It was recommended app. But I cant open Skype. I go start>internet>skype click and nothing.
How can I fix It ?
Thank You

.................

i tried this commands
[How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype/932189)
Now I have two skype icon in apps panel, 
but i can't open any one :D

```
valdovas@new-host:~$ sudo apt-get remove skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "skype", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install skype"

E: Unable to locate package skype

valdovas@new-host:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

No apt package "skype", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install skype"

E: Unable to locate package skype

valdovas@new-host:~$ snap install skype
snap "skype" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

valdovas@new-host:~$ wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
--2019-01-10 01:06:35--  https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
Resolving repo.skype.com (repo.skype.com)... 72.247.172.238, 2a02:26f0:e2:48d::1263, 2a02:26f0:e2:48a::1263
Connecting to repo.skype.com (repo.skype.com)|72.247.172.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 73441958 (70M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘skypeforlinux-64.deb’

skypeforlinux-64.deb            100%[====================================================>]  70,04M  6,74MB/s    in 11s     

2019-01-10 01:06:46 (6,56 MB/s) - ‘skypeforlinux-64.deb’ saved [73441958/73441958]

valdovas@new-host:~$ sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package skypeforlinux.
(Reading database ... 226508 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skypeforlinux-64.deb ...
Unpacking skypeforlinux (8.34.0.78) ...
Setting up skypeforlinux (8.34.0.78) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...

valdovas@new-host:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.

valdovas@new-host:~$
```

Comment: Yes I can go to terminal , tell me what to write?

Comment: valdovas@new-host:~$ skype
valdovas@new-host:~$

Comment: This is everything :)

Comment: valdovas@new-host:~$ mkdir ~/.Skype/Logs then skype then ls -lh ~/.Skype/Logs/
mkdir: invalid option -- 'l'
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
valdovas@new-host:~$

Comment: valdovas@new-host:~$ mkdir ~/.Skype/Logs
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/valdovas/.Skype/Logs’: No such file or directory
valdovas@new-host:~$ ls -lh ~/.Skype/Logs/
ls: cannot access '/home/valdovas/.Skype/Logs/': No such file or directory
valdovas@new-host:~$

Comment: valdovas@new-host:~$ mkdir ~/.Skype/Logs
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/valdovas/.Skype/Logs’: No such file or directory
valdovas@new-host:~$ skype
valdovas@new-host:~$ ls -lh ~/.Skype/Logs/
ls: cannot access '/home/valdovas/.Skype/Logs/': No such file or directory
valdovas@new-host:~$

Comment: Please edit the question and add out of `cat ~/.config/skypeforlinux/logs/skype-startup.log` to the question.

Comment: valdovas@new-host:~$ cat ~/.config/skypeforlinux/logs/skype-startup.log
cat: /home/valdovas/.config/skypeforlinux/logs/skype-startup.log: No such file or directory
valdovas@new-host:~$