# Unreadable charaters on Skype (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) add file

Tags: skype

When I try to add a file to a Skype message I get a screen similar to one I've attached.
Thank you[image]

Comment: check you have microsoft fonts installed (`ttf-mscorefonts-installer`)

Comment: Hello, I added the recommended font, verified in the Fonts but no changes in the Add File window

Comment: Did you re-build the font-cache?  (`fc-cache`) though your GUI may require a logout & login again to notice a rebuilt font-cache too...

Comment: $ sudo fc-cache -f -v, restarted, no changes 8-(

Comment: How did you add skype?  if it's via *snap* there is a font cache in the snap directory that you can clean, and it'll be re-created next time you start the program (I don't have `skype` as snap installed so I can't search for it sorry on thss box)

Comment: I deleted snap and installed from the web. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7498/how-do-i-install-skype)