# gimp 2.10 crashes (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, gimp

My GIMP worked fine until today. Today I started GIMP, and there are rectangular characters similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336384/unreadable-charaters-on-skype-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-add-file) posting. I've reinstalled GIMP. After re-installation GIMP crashes and still rectangular characters.
I ran from the terminal, and this is what I got

<$ gimp
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object weight does not accept value [50 200)
/snap/gimp/372/usr/bin/gimp: Gimp-Text-CRITICAL: gimp_font_factory_load_names: assertion 'fontset' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_width > 0' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_get_width: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_get_height: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.293: gdk_pixbuf_get_pixels_with_length: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.294: gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 13:09:42.294: gdk_pixbuf_get_n_channels: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(gimp:8545): GLib-ERROR **: 13:09:42.294: ../../../../glib/gmem.c:333: overflow allocating 18446744073709551615*18446744073709551615 bytes

(script-fu:8627): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: 13:09:42.856: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)>

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the snap-install and re-installed it from ppa.
That worked for me.